# How to update UserProfile Properties on Sharepoint Online 2013 (O365)

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-userprofile

I've been trying to update a user profile properties using c# on Sharepoint Online 2013.
I can't find how to do it, can someone help me?

Here is what i have to do:

I have a lot of custom properties on User Profile, and i need to edit it on an Provider-Hosted app.

I'm using PersonProperties and PeopleManager to get the data, so how to update that?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This will probably be of some help](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/rymoore/updating-o365-sharepoint-user-profile-properties-with-c-61062)

Using the UserProfileService, this class should help with your issue

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using O365ProfileUpdate.UserProfileServiceRef;

    public class O365Helper
    {
        private readonly UserProfileService _userProfileService;
        private readonly Uri _targetAdminSite;

        public O365Helper(UserProfileService userProfileService, Uri targetAdminSite, string adminUsername,
                          string adminPassword)
        {
            _userProfileService = userProfileService;
            _targetAdminSite = targetAdminSite;


            var authenticated = AuthenticateAdministrator(adminUsername, adminPassword);

            if (!authenticated)
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unable to authenticate administrator");
        }

        public PropertyData GetProfileProperty(string login, string propertyName)
        {
            var memLogin = GetMembershipLogin(login);

            return _userProfileService.GetUserPropertyByAccountName(memLogin, propertyName);
        }

        public bool UpdateProfileProperty(string login, string key, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                var valueData = new ValueData {Value = value};

                var newdata = new PropertyData[1];
                newdata[0] = new PropertyData {Name = key, Values = new ValueData[1]};
                newdata[0].Values[0] = valueData;
                newdata[0].IsValueChanged = true;

                var memLogin = GetMembershipLogin(login);

                _userProfileService.ModifyUserPropertyByAccountName(memLogin, newdata);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private bool AuthenticateAdministrator(string login, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password)
                {
                    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                }

                var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

                string authCookieValue = onlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(_targetAdminSite);
                var cookieVal = authCookieValue.TrimStart("SPOIDCRL=".ToCharArray());

                _userProfileService.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                _userProfileService.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(
                                                            "FedAuth",
                                                            cookieVal,
                                                            String.Empty,
                                                            _targetAdminSite.Authority));
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private string GetMembershipLogin(string login)
        {
            return "i:0#.f|membership|" + login;
        }
    }
```

adminUsername and adminPassword are the credentials for a user with administrative privileges (so, probably you) in your instance

The UserProfileService can be found in the UserProfileService.asmx endpoint in your O365 ADMIN site

Comment: Thanks for the answer Karma. I'll try this and let you know!